# Webkit animation works fine in chrome, but not in safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, css

I attempting to create a pulse animation. So far it works fine in chrome, but in Safari it doesn't do anything.

```
#cogFlower:hover
{   
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   0%   { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
   25%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);}
   50%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
   75%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
  }
```

If you want to see a demo of what I'm doing, you can view it here:
http://www.thestoicsband.com/

*the login details are:
username: guest, password: guest123*

Thanks for your help.

Cheers Will

Answer (score 3):

When you're using keyframes, you must include *at least* `0%` and `100%` keyframes. So you can fix this problem by simply modifying your CSS like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0%   { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  25%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);}
  50%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
  75%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
  100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
}
```

Alternatively, the `from` and `to` keywords can be used in place of the start and end percentages:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  25%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);}
  50%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
  75%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
  to   { -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very strange. It seems if you add `to` at the end of the keyframes the animation works in Safari.

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   0% { 
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   25% { 
       -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   }
   50% {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   }
   75% {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
   }
   to {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.